# What parameters does Visual Studio pass to MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When Visual Studio runs a build, it runs MSBuild to do the majority of the work. If you pass the .sln file to MSBuild, with appropriate Configuration and Platform properties, it will build your solution similarly to how Visual Studio would.

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

However, there *are* differences: sometimes a build will error through MSBuild and not through Visual Studio, or vice-versa.

What parameters does Visual Studio pass into MSBuild to influence the process? Is there some way to see the parameters it's passing as a build is is executed?

Comment: Technically, it does not run `MSBuild.exe` but hosts the build engine internally, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Visual Studio does not execute `MSBuild.exe`, but hosts the build engine itself (by means of the `Microsoft.Build.*` assemblies) - at least that is the case for the default C# project system. Other languages, addins, packages, etc. might do it differently.

Actually, there was a post series on the Microsoft blogs about this, I'm trying to find them and update this answer.

*UPDATE*: Found it again. Look for the "MSBuild in Visual Studio" posts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/post-summary-msbuild-in-visual-studio).

Concerning your original question, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx) page might help you further. Also you could go to "Tools", "Options", "Projects and Solutions", "Build and Run" and increase the MSBuild output verbosity. With "Diagnostic" you should basically see every property that is set upon starting the build.

Comment: I could never see an external MSBuild process, so I expected the hosting was the case. The diagnostic setting sounds close to what I want, but it does make it harder to understand the equivalent MSBuild command-line syntax, if one even exists.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero That's the point - there is no such command-line. You would have to come up with it by "reverse engineering" the properties, sort of.

Comment: I found this as a good reference article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/06/508981.aspx. I would edit it into your answer, but thought it might be a bit presumptive. Perhaps you'd like to add this so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Is this still true in 2015? Will this be true with Roslyn?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Frankly, I have no idea and have not yet found the time to look into VS2015 at all ;-) But I _thought_ that Roslyn uses some sort of client/server compile architecture, no? If so, than I would guess that VS would only be another client (like the new csc.exe is another). But again, totally not sure here.

Answer (score 12):

First off, you can run msbuild with the `/v:diag` argument to get diagnostic-level logging. This can really help in figuring out why a build is failing.

Otherwise, yes, if you use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), you can monitor for process start events where you can see the specific command-line sent to the process.

Specifically:

- Run Process Monitor
- Filter » Filter...
- `Operation` `is` `Process Create` » Add
- `Operation` `is` `Process Start` » Add
- OK
- Run your build through VS and through command-line msbuild
- See the command-line arguments in the Detail column

Comment: This would be the way to go, if MSBuild was executed as a separate process; unfortunately, at least in Visual Studio 2010, it doesn't show up as a separate process.