# Show MSBuild command during build or package in output window of Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

When Visual Studio build or package Solution, output window comes with

`------ Build started: XXXX...`

But, can I see actual command to execute MSBuild with every switches, which are configured in Project/Solution? Such as

```
c:\xxx\yyy\MSBuild.exe /t:compile /switches ...
------ Build started: XXXX...
```

I want to make a script to automate a packaging process. I can create it by myself, but it'd be helpful if I can see that.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932164/what-parameters-does-visual-studio-pass-to-msbuild

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I might need an add-on to render final MSBuild command prior to compiling output even VS doesn't run MSBuild internally.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft proviedes the [ProjectSystemTools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools) that allows you to do build logging. It can log both the design time builds (e.g. what happens when you load the project or when NuGet restores packages) as well as the actual build processes.