# How do I know exactly how MSBuild is being invoked inside the VS IDE in order to exactly duplicate on the command line?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015, if that matters.

If I use MSbuild on a project in my solution on the command line, I can of course specify a number of switches to alter the behavior and output.  However, the build called from within Visual Studio is not controlled with switches, but by setting various properties in the IDE.

The output from MSbuild in VS is minimal.  It shows errors and warnings and what failed and what succeeded.  The output from MSBuild on the command line shows more information.

How do I know when I have selected command line options that exactly mimic what is happening when inside Visual studio?  How can I get visual studio to give me the same output I get when using MSBuild on the command line?

Many thanks.

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting.

Comment: According to their GitHub repo discussions, Visual Studio does not 100% use MSBuild via command line. There does exist other logic which you might not be able replicate. Though if you just want to see the same level of logging, follow the comment from Hans.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932164/what-parameters-does-visual-studio-pass-to-msbuild

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comments.  And for the pointer to the other StackOverflow discussion.  Very helpful.  But also a bit breathtaking... somehow (on purpose) Microsoft has set things up so that you can't replicate a build from in the IDE outside the IDE exactly?  That seems, well, odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions seems to be completely answered in the comments kindly made on the initial question, and in the referenced stackoverflow, github, and MSDN discussions.  Seems like an odd engineering choice to me, but I don't think that will change anything!