# How to find out the command Visual Studio sends to MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to use MSBuild in a CI/CD engine, and I need to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC application using it.

I want to know what Visual Studio sends to the MSBuild when we build/publish a project, and send that exactly to MSBuild.

Is there anyway that we can find out the command Visual Studio 2017 sends to MSBuild to build/publish a .NET Core project?

**Update:** To those who say that VS uses MSBuild API, simply kill all `MSBuild.exe` processes, then build a project/solution via VS, and you'll see that `MSBuild.exe` is coming back into the processes list (viewed via Task Manager). So, what's the explanation? If VS uses API, then that API should run inside `devenv.exe` process and no instance of `MSBuild.exe` should appear inside Task Manager. Right?

**Update 2**: Does `devenv.exe` expose its publish functionality?

Comment: Visual Studio uses MSBuild managed API to perform the tasks, so you won't capture the commands. For .NET Core projects, use `dotnet`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What parameters does Visual Studio pass to MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932164/what-parameters-does-visual-studio-pass-to-msbuild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway that we can find out the command Visual Studio 2017 sends to MSBuild to build/publish a .NET Core project?

No, you can not find out the command Visual Studio 2017 sends to MSBuild to build/publish a .NET Core project. Because Visual Studio uses [MSBuild API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/dd393574.aspx) to execute a series of tasks to accomplish build/publish:

> Visual Studio uses MSBuild to load and build managed projects. The project files in Visual Studio (.csproj,.vbproj, vcxproj, and others) contain MSBuild XML code that executes when you build a project by using the IDE. Visual Studio projects import all the necessary settings and build processes to do typical development work, but you can extend or modify them from within Visual Studio or by using an XML editor.

So there is no command sends to MSBuild, we won't capture the commands. You can check the build log after change MSBuild output verbosity to "`Diagnostic`" or "`Detailed`" to verify the existence of the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I hope those [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932164/what-parameters-does-visual-studio-pass-to-msbuild) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373841/can-i-view-what-build-commands-are-actually-executed-with-msbuild) helped you somehow, they are old but may give you some guidance to the solution you are lookin for.